# Threads/Sockets limits in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets, posix

First of all: sorry for my english.
Guys, I have a trouble with POSIX sockets and/or pthreads. I'm developing on embedded device(ARM9 CPU). On the device will work multithread tcp server. And it will be able to process a lot of incoming connections. Server gets connection from client and increase counter variable(unsigned int counter). Clients routines will run in separate threads. All clients will use 1 singleton class instance(in this class will be opened and closed same files). Clients works with files, then client thread closes connection socket, and calls pthread_exit().
So, my tcp server can't handle more than 250 threads(counter = 249 +1(server thread). And I got "Resource temporary unavailable". What's the problem?

Comment: Check `ulimit` to see what the limitations are, my guess is your probably reaching it.

Comment: I checked it, ulimit says that I can use 900+ (probably 994) threads.

Comment: BTW, do you mean 250 concurrent threads (or have some of those threads already terminated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you hit the thread limit - or as mentioned run out of virtual process address space due to the number of threads - you're.... doing it wrong. More threads don't scale. Especially not when doing embedded programming. You can handle requests on a thread pool instead. Use [`poll(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) to handle many connections on fewer threads. This is prettty well-trod territory and libraries (like ACE, asio) have been leveraging this model for good reason

The 'thread-per-request' model is mainly popular because of it's (perceived) simple design.

As long as you keep connections on a single *logical* thread (sometimes known as a *strand*) there is no real difference, though.

Also, if the handling of a request involves no blocking operations, you can never do better than polling and handling on a single thread after all: you can use the 'backlog' feature of bind/accept to let the *kernel* worry about pending connections for you! (Note: this assumed a single core CPU, on a dual core CPU this kind of processing would be optimal with one thread per CPU)

**Edit** Addition Re:

> ulimit shows how much threads can OS handle, right? If yes, ulimit does not solve my problem because my app uses ~10-15 threads in same time.

If that's the case, you should really double check that you are joining *or* detaching all threads properly. Also think of the synchronization objects; if you consistently forget to call the relevant pthread *_destroy functions, you'll run into the limits even without needing it. That would of course be a *resource leak*. Some tools may be able to help you spot them (vlagrind/helgrind come to mind)

Comment: @Edward: added a comment in response to a comment by Edward

Comment: Thank you. pthread_detach solved my problem. Also thanx for more information abouthreads. It was very usefull!

Answer (score 0):

Use **ulimit -n** to check the number of file system handles. You can increase it for your current session if the number is too low.

Also you can edit /etc/security/limits.conf and to set a permanent limit

Comment: Ok. Can I define somewhere something to be able create unlimit count of thread, of course if there is free memory and cpu time?

Comment: ulimit shows how much threads can OS handle, right? If yes, ulimit does not solve my problem because my app uses ~10-15 threads in same time.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the first limit you are hitting on 32-bit systems is that you are running out of virtual address space when using default stack sizes.

Try explicitly specifying the stack size when creating threads (to less than 1 MB) or setting the default stack size with "ulimit -s".

Also note that you need to either pthread_detach or pthread_join your threads so that all resources will be freed.

Comment: My client thread before exiting clears all pointers, closes all descriptors. And it does not use much memory. Does pthread clear stack after exitng?

Comment: This stack is deallocated when the thread properly terminates. Are you detaching the threads (pthread_detach) or joining (pthread_join)?

Comment: don't forget you can set the stacksize using pthread attributes at creation ([`pthread_attr_setstacksize`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setstacksize))