# Stream Socket Server cannot handle more than 382 threads(one per connection) in Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to write a server program which forks a process for handling multiple client connections which creates one thread per connection. But the maximum number of threads this process can create never exceeds 382.

Why can't I create more number of threads which handle one file descriptor for communicating with one client while the file descriptor limit per process is 1024 in Linux?

I'm using a system running Kubuntu on Core-i3 with 2GB ram.

Here is the code for main function..

```
int server_start(void)
{
listen(skid,10000);
scnt=0;
printf("Server Listening at port:%d\n",serdt.port);
for(scnt=0;scnt<1000;)
{
        sdata->cpid[scnt]=fork();
        switch(sdata->cpid[scnt])
        {
            case -1:    printf("Could not Fork\n"); break;
            case  0:    mxsubserver(scnt); exit(0);
            default:    scnt++; break;
        }
//  }
    //check for other parameters
    pause();
}
while(1);
}
```

Variable not declared in the function are global variables. I have a blank action handler for signal number 50 for breaking out of the pause.

The forked process sends the signal to the parent(this) process when the limit(file descriptor) is reached and then it will fork a new process. Below is the server process code called after fork in above code...

```
typedef struct
{
    int cln;
    int cnt;
    int fd;
    pthread_t ptid;
}service_d;

void mxsubserver(int cln)
{//cln is the child sub-server number
int ln,fd,rfp;
pthread_t ptid;
pthread_attr_t attr;
iflag=1;

sub_data = shmat(shmid,NULL,SHM_RND);

signal(SIGINT,sub_sigint);
signal(SIGPIPE,sub_sigpipe);
signal(50,SIG_DFL);
parg = malloc(sizeof(service_d));
parg->cln = cln;
cnt=0;
printf("Server Instance %d Started\n",cln);
for(cnt=0;;)
{
    if(iflag)
    {
        cnt++;
        ln = (socklen_t)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        fd = accept(skid,(struct sockaddr *)&sktaddr,&ln);
        parg->fd=fd;
        parg->cnt=(cln*1000)+cnt;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_create(&(parg->ptid),&attr,&service,parg);
        pthread_detach(parg->ptid);
        pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
        sub_data->openfd[cln]=cnt;
    }
    if(cnt>=1000)
    {
        printf("Limit Reached\n");
        iflag=getppid();
        printf("Signalling Parent\n");
        kill(iflag,50);
        iflag=0;
        pause();
    }
    if(cnt==0)
    {
        free(parg);
        exit(0);
    }
}
kill(getppid(),50);
while(1);
return;
}
void sub_sigint(int sn)
{
free(parg);
shmdt(sub_data);
exit(0);
}

void sub_sigpipe(int sn)
{
cnt--;
iflag=1;
}

void* service(void *arg)
{//handle the client requests
int fd,cln,l,ol;
char im[100],*msg="This is from Server\n";
service_d *srd;

srd = (service_d*)arg;
//pthread_detach(srd->ptid);
fd = srd->fd;
cln = srd->cnt;
printf("service cln: %d f: %d\n",cln,iflag);
ol=strlen(msg);

while(1)
{
    read(fd,&l,sizeof(int)); //open to get sigpipe error if client closes
    if(read(fd,im,l)<0) break;
    im[l]='\0';
//  printf("Server %d thread %d: Got >> %s\n",srd->cln,cln,im);
    if(write(fd,&ol,sizeof(int))<0) break;
    if(write(fd,msg,ol)<0) break;;
}
close(fd);
pthread_exit("Done\n");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What about `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`? And `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`?

Comment: Most likely you're hitting some kind of resource limit, I'd suspect that the default setting for stack size is eating up all your virtual address space in the process. What does stack size from `ulimit -a` tell you?

Comment: pid_max is 32768 and thread_max is 29138. Stack size is 8192kbytes.

Comment: OT: `ln` should be of type `socklen_t` not `int`.

Comment: But how can it eat up the virtual address space with just 382  file descriptors open and doing nothing but waiting using accept call. The program doesn't go beyond the 382nd connection. If I change the max thread created in the forked process from 1000 to 380. Then the server handles around 9000 connections simultaneously, but hangs after that. Also I wrote a program for UNIX domain sockets which handled 1000 clients per process(server instance) and a total of 10,000 clients running on the same system. But this one just hangs.

Comment: Does `service()` `close()` `parg->fd` when done?

Comment: "*But the maximum number of threads this process can create never exceeds 382.*" you get which error for exactly which call? In case you do not get an error, exactly where does the code block?

Comment: How would `mxsubserver()` get beyond the `pause()` which is called after `1000` `accept()`s? It looks like the `fork()`ed process never ends.

Comment: It is not a good idea to change your question after comments/answers had been given, as this might make those comments/answers ununderstandable.

Comment: I rolled back your last change therefore.

Comment: Yes, it closes the fd. I have edited the question and have included the code for service and SIGPIPE signal handler.

Comment: The main server when receives Ctrl+C, it kills all its child processes and the program terminates properly. It gives no error, it just stops after 382nd or 381st thread.

Comment: There is a race with passing arguments to the threads if the thread function is slower then `accept()`ing occurs. You want to move this `parg = malloc(sizeof(service_d));` inside the `for(;;)` loop and adjust the calls to `free()` accordingly, that is move it into the thread function.

Comment: "*it just stops*" "*stops*" in the sense of "ends" or does it block? If the latter on which call?

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and placed malloc inside the loop without any success. The program actually kept on accepting the requests but doesn't create any thread after 382nd accept.Then after accepting 1000th request, server forks another instance and the same is repeated.

Comment: The result returned by read() is not handled fully and correctly.  The assumption that 'read(fd,im,l)' will read 'l' bytes is invalid and the resulting protocol error is likely to result in grave problems with 'read(fd,&l,sizeof(int));', which can either return a protocol-misaligned int with a value that is larger than your buffer, (which you do not check for - sucks), or simply return less than 'sizeof(int)' bytes, (which you do not check for - sucks) which again is liikely to cause a gross read length error/stackoverflow.

Comment: You MUST handle fully the results returned from system calls like read().  It can be less than 0, (handled in your code - good), 0, (connection closed by peer - not handled in your code - bad), or greater than 0, (number of bytes actually received - not handled in your code -  VERY BAD).

Comment: Don't bother worrying about the threading until you have fixed your basic protocol errors.

Comment: My client program first writes the length of the buffer and then the message, which is constant and repeats this in a while loop. So this doesn't cause any problems. And I want the the server to get the SIGPIPE signal for reading a broken pipe when client exists. Therefore I haven't checked it. In rest of the code read/write will return -1 and break the loop and close the connection, while handler for SIGPIPE will decrement the count and make room for one extra connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it.

Saw this thread: [Threads/Sockets limits in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581257/threads-sockets-limits-in-linux?rq=1)

The default stack size is 8MB. When I create 382 threads, total size of the stacks created for all the threads is 8x382 i.e, around 3GB.

Therefore I reduced the stack size to 30KB using `pthread_attr_setstacksize`.
Now after connecting to around 6000 clients it must say something like `libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work` . This can be solved by running the command: `apt-get install libgcc1-dbg` as root.